# How to use bit-wise operators in Laravel in database query

Tags: php, laravel

For example:

`select * from table where a&b = b;`

I've tried

`where([ ['a'&$b, $b] ])->get();` and `where([ [['a', '&', $b], $b] ])->get();`

They all failed.
`a` is a column, `$b` is a variable.

Comment: @Chen.you can try raw quries in laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `whereRaw`

```
whereRaw('a&b = b')->get();
```